# Pass an INotifyProperty in a class so that the changes propagate back

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've implemented a class that takes care of loading objects asynchronously and takes care of changing the cursor accordingly, namely in the **UpdateCursor** method:

```
    static Cursor cursor;

    public AsyncLoader(Func<CbT> request, Callback callback, Cursor cursor)
    {
        this.request = request;
        this.callback = callback;
        AsyncLoader<CbT>.cursor = cursor;

        LatestRequestId = Guid.NewGuid();
        UpdateCursor();
        ...
    }

    void UpdateCursor()
    {
        if (LatestRequestId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
        }
    }
```

In the class where I'm going to use this class I have the Cursor property which implements INotifyProperty and it's bound to the window's cursor:

```
    private Cursor _CurrentCursor;
    public Cursor CurrentCursor
    {
        get { return _CurrentCursor; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _CurrentCursor)
            {
                _CurrentCursor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCursor");
            }
        }
    }
```

In the View:

```
    Cursor="{Binding CurrentCursor}"
```

The question is, how can I pass the CurrentCursor to the AsyncLoader, so that when the UpdateCursor runs, the changes will be reflected back to the CurrentCursor and fire the PopertyChange event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution would be to create an interface

```
interface ICursorHolder{
    Cursor CurrentCursor{get;set;}
}
```

Pass instance of type ICursorHolder to the AsyncLoader and to implement this interface in your class with Cursor property

```
public AsyncLoader(Func<CbT> request, Callback callback, ICursorHolder cursorHolder)
{
    this.request = request;
    this.callback = callback;
    AsyncLoader<CbT>.cursorHolder = cursorHolder;//change according to your logic

    LatestRequestId = Guid.NewGuid();
    UpdateCursor();
    ...
}

void UpdateCursor()
{
    if (LatestRequestId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        cursorHolder.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
    else
    {
        cursorHolder.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
    }
}
```

and your class

```
public class ShellPresenter: PresenterBase, ICursorHolder{   
    private Cursor _CurrentCursor;
    public Cursor CurrentCursor
    {
        get { return _CurrentCursor; }
        set {
            if (value != _CurrentCursor){
                _CurrentCursor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCursor");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

**Upd1**

Updated sample code

**Upd2**

```
private void CallAsync(){
   ShellPresenter shell=GetInstance();
   Loader.AsyncLoader(request,callback, shell);

}
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks! One more question though: my presenter will implement this interface as such: `public class ShellPresenter : PresenterBase, ICursorHolder` and have an instance in it: `ICursorHolder cursor;` and then I initialize it in the constructor: `cursor = this;`. Is this the correct way to do it in the constructor?

Comment: @CloneXpert if I understood you right you want in ShellPresenter to have property of type ICursorHolder? Than it's not right, ShellPresenter will not change, you just have to add an interface in the class header. If I misunderstood you, explain in more detailed. I have updated the code in my Answer

Comment: that's how I wanted to do first, but I didn't know how to pass this CurrentCursor in the AsyncLoader if it expects ICursorHolder? Do I need to pass `this`? Sorry for being confusing...

Comment: yes that's basically the same :) thanks again, I'll mark your answer as the solution, have a nice day!